# Spaghetti plot in R with repeated measurements

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, anova

I would like to realize a spaghetti plot in R to visualize differences between two conditions for every single participant. I computed a repeated measurements ANOVA with the factors CRITICALITY (critical, non-critical) and LATERALITY (ipsilateral, contralateral). My data looks the following and can be found here:

```
    subject cond       power      laterality      criticality
1   P02   CL_CRIT       -362.7    contralateral   crit
2   P03   CL_CRIT       -186.8    contralateral   crit
3   P13   CL_CRIT       -314.6    contralateral   crit
4   P15   CL_CRIT       -353.3    contralateral   crit
5   P17   CL_CRIT       -457.8    contralateral   crit
6   P18   CL_CRIT       -219.3    contralateral   crit
7   P19   CL_CRIT       -124.0    contralateral   crit
8   P25   CL_CRIT       -329.5    contralateral   crit
9   P27   CL_CRIT       -286.9    contralateral   crit
37  P02   CL_NCRIT      -28.6     contralateral   non-critical
38  P03   CL_NCRIT      -269.3    contralateral   non-critical
39  P13   CL_NCRIT      -363.8    contralateral   non-critical
40  P15   CL_NCRIT      -255.1    contralateral   non-critical
```

[Link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwac4s95vif9yon/mu_power.csv?dl=0)

With the following code I am able to plot the single data points of all participants:

```
### plot single values
stim.group <- mu_power
pd <- position_dodge(0.3) # move data .03 to the left and right
pp <- ggplot(stim.group, aes(x=critical, y=power, colour=laterality)) +
geom_point(position=pd) + ylab("mu power")
pp
```

What I want now is a plot where, separately for the levels ipsilateral and contralateral, the critical and non-critical datapoints of every single participant are connected. Here is a self-drawn sample of what I am aiming at:
[image: SAMPLE]

I searched on the internet for quite some time but did not find any solution.

Comment: This type of chart is also called _bump chart_ or _slopegraph_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
df <- read.table("path/to/your/data")
df$sub_lat <- paste(df$subject, df$laterality)

ggplot(df, aes(x=critical, y=power)) + 
  geom_point(aes(group = sub_lat, color = laterality)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = sub_lat, color = laterality)) +
  xlab("critical") +
  ylab("sensorimotor_mu_nogo power")
```

Resulting in this plot:
[image: spaghetti plot]

I hope this is what you need/want

Comment: Hey jkrainer, thanks very much for your very quick reply! I was a bit shocked, how fast I got an answer :-). Unfortunately your solution does not work for me, when I try it out the following image appears: [New Plot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edlaopwe50y9hev/Rplot.jpeg?dl=0).

Comment: hello Matthias, after looking at the data in your dropbox i saw that the points are not only grouped by subject but by the combination of subject and laterality. I hope this is right now. I edited my answer above :)

Comment: hello jkrainer, you made my day - thanks a lot! In your code one just has to replace "sub_cond" by "sub_lat" and then it works for me! Thank you very much :-).

Answer (score 2):

Also see this:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = criticality, y = power,
                           group = subject, color = laterality))
```